# How to test if reactive values is null in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny app, I'd like to test if a reactive value created with an eventReactive() exists.
I tried is.null() but it doesn't work.
Here a reproducible example.
In my real work, there are more instructions in the eventReactive...

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("create_object", "Create Object"),
  actionButton("validation", "validation"),
  DTOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Creating an event reactive object
  my_object <- eventReactive(input$create_object, {
    head(iris)
  })
  
  if (is.null(my_object())) {

    res <- my_object() |>
      select(Petal.Length)

  } else {
    res <- iris |>
      select(Petal.Width)
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$validation, {
    
    output$result <- renderDT({
      iris
    })
    
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The answer you accepted won't work. Because the value of a reactive conductor which "does not exist" is not `NULL`. So you cannot test with `is.null`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent it's been updated, it now works, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be attempting to access `my_object()` outside of a reactive block. It's not clear what you are trying to do with `res` (never used), but I think you're trying to do something like:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Creating an event reactive object
  my_object <- eventReactive(input$create_object, {
    head(iris)
  })
  
  res <- eventReactive(my_object(), {
    if (is.null(my_object())) {              # MOVE to inside a reactive block
      res <- my_object() |>
        select(Petal.Length)
    } else {
      res <- iris |>
        select(Petal.Width)
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$validation, {
    output$result <- renderDT({
      res()                                  # CHANGE
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This will doubly not work: if `my_object()` "does not exist", that does not mean it is `NULL`; moreover if `my_object()` were `NULL`, then `eventReactive(my_object()` would not react, because there's the default option `ignoreNULL=TRUE`. The way to go is given in my answer, using `tryCatch`. If `my_object()` "does not exists", that actually means that `my_object()` throws a `shiny.silent.error`.

Comment: (1) If `my_object()` does not exist, we have a race condition in `shiny` that goes well out of bounds of this question. Is there a clear way to demonstrate `could not find function "my_object"` or `object 'my_object' not found`? (2) Thanks for the reminder about `ignoreNULL=`.

Comment: r2evans> The question is not the same as the one stated in the title. It is: *"to test if a reactive value created with an eventReactive() exists"*. The word "exists" is not the right one, rigorously. Here that means that `my_object()` is `head(iris)`. I think, not sure, that the correct word is "invalidated". Anyway, the question is not the one of the title: it is not about knowing whether a the value returned by a reactive conductor is `NULL`. IMHO the OP believed that "does not exist" = "is `NULL`". Actually "does not exist" = "throws a shiny silent error". You don't answer the question.

Comment: Interesting, I interpreted it differently, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do. But maybe you can use `req`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("create_object", "Click me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  my_object <- eventReactive(input$create_object, {
    head(iris)
  })
  
  my_object_exists <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  observe({
    req(my_object())
    my_object_exists(TRUE)
  })
  
  res <- reactive({
    if(my_object_exists()) {
      my_object() |>
        select(Petal.Length)
    } else {
      iris |>
        select(Petal.Width)
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As a side note, don't nest an output slot inside an observer as you do here:

```r
  observeEvent(input$validation, {
    
    output$result <- renderDT({
      iris
    })
    
  })
```

Instead, you can use `req` for example:

```r
    output$result <- renderDT({
      req(input$validation)
      iris
    })
```

---

## EDIT: better solution

Rather use `tryCatch`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("create_object", "Click me")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  my_object <- eventReactive(input$create_object, {
    head(iris)
  })

  observe({
    myObjectExists <- tryCatch({
      my_object()
      TRUE
    },
    shiny.silent.error = function(e) {
      FALSE
    })
    print(myObjectExists)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So you can use it in a reactive conductor:

```
myObjectExists <- reactive({
    tryCatch({
      my_object()
      TRUE
    },
    shiny.silent.error = function(e) {
      FALSE
    })
})
```